# Android Notification at time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am looking for hours now how to do this exactly:

I want that every day (except weekends) a notification is sent at a time (let's say 18:00 (= 6pm)) except for when the app is open already. It's basically like the gmail app when you receive a mail.
When the user clicks the notification it should disappear and should be brought to the MainActivity.

I have tried numerous things with the AlarmManager, but none have resulted in a notification showing up.

The code I tried, which I feel is pretty close to being correct, is following: 
In my MainActivity:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

My NotificationService:

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {



    public NotificationService() {
        super("NotificationService");
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "reminder", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent , 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "It's about time", "You should open the app now", contentIntent);
        nm.notify(1, notification);
    }
}
```

Notice I use deprecated stuff because this was even the only way a notification ever showed up while not working with the AlarmManager. If possible, please react with a solution that does not have the deprecated stuff in it, but with up to date stuff :P.

Many many many thanks in advance!!!

Kindest regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I was able to find the solution:

```
private void handleNotification() {
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);
}
```

This is my custom `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        int dayOfWeek = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
        if(dayOfWeek != 1 && dayOfWeek != 7) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.message_box_title))
                    .setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.message_timesheet_not_up_to_date));
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

And this in the manifest in the application tag:

```
<receiver
        android:name="be.menis.timesheet.service.AlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

Comment: what is this `android:name="be.menis.timesheet.service.AlarmReceiver"`??
I want to set up notification at 10AM daily

Comment: @ashish that is the application package name and location of the receiver

Comment: Thanks for the code, i'm testing it now. But does anyone knows if i'll set a new alarm every time i run this code? if so, i should be very careful with it...

Comment: does this run even if you close the application?

Comment: Yes, it used to run then. However, as you see, this has been a long time ago, so I'm not 100% sure if the app was still running in the background or if it was actually closed. I believe it really was closed :).