# NotificationCompat.Builder missing build() method

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, alarmmanager

I want to do exactly, what he does: [Android Notification at time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053996/android-notification-at-time) 
But in my AlarmReceiver class, I have an error: The method build() is undefined for the type NotificationCompat.Builder, at line: mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

In android developer site is a similar code, but the same error appears(http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may be on an older version of the Android Support package. Make sure that your project has a current copy of `android-support-v4.jar` or `android-support-v13.jar` in `libs/`.

Comment: or use new NotificationCompat.Builder(context) for target >= Honeycomb as mentioned in another question!

Answer (score 4):

It appears that there's a broken version of the Android Support package out there. Specifically, [the one currently being deployed in ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/commit/0d58f694a3146a8d277bb20f5124fe07b26f8e3d#diff-de9874363b890e7092c41c7380af0db1).

I'd recommend always using the latest `android-support-v4.jar` from inside the Android SDK. You'll find it in `[android-sdk]/extras/android/support/v4`.

Comment: Ran into this issue too after downgrading v4 support to match ActionBarSherlock - sigh...

Comment: This is a very old answer; I thoroughly encourage you to stop using ActionBarSherlock in favor of the support library.

Comment: This looks like a promising article on the topic: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat/

Comment: Yes, it is! Nice to see some love for @WolframRittmeyer!

Comment: Looks like this SO item is another relevant resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933944/what-are-the-common-issues-when-migrating-from-actionbarsherlock-to-actionbarcom