# Submenu in actionbar shows in dialogue

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am using AppCompact theme.
My application working fine.
But submenu openes in dialogue below android 3.0

on device android 4.0 and on device android 2.3

[image] [image]

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <!-- Search Widget -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>



    <!-- Options -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/overflow_options"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:title="@string/action_overflow"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/form1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_location"
                android:title="Profile"
                yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/form2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_location"
                android:title="My Video"
                yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/form3"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_location"
                android:title="Upload Video"
                yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
             <item
                android:id="@+id/form4"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_location"
                android:title="Friends"
                yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>

        </menu>
    </item>


    <!-- Refresh -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>


    <!-- Help -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Login"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_help"/>

    <!-- Setting -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/setting"/>

</menu>
```

What i am missing ? I want to implement my menu same as in android 4.0.

Comment: Do you us AppCompat ?

Comment: yes i am using APPCompact

Comment: similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158710/actionbar-compat-do-not-show-dropdown-menu. I am not sure if that fixes haven't tried myself

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show options as overflow you have to use `android:showAsAction="never"` as you are doing with your Help and Settings menu item.

However if want to show a Drop down menu similar to the menu that is shown when overflow icon is clicked you have to make [Popup menu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html).

[Link](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example) to the nice tutorial

Comment: It will. Just show it when sync menu item is tapped.

Comment: I know about Popup menu but at first I want to implement it without using Popup