# What's the enhancement of AppCompatActivity over ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity, appcompatactivity

`android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` was added into the latest v7 support library as a new feature yesterday.

It is said that `ActionBarActivity` has been deprecated in favor of the new `AppCompatActivity` and that `AppCompatActivity` is base class for activities that use the support library action bar features. So, what are new features of `AppCompatActivity` over `ActionBarActivity`? What enhancements do `AppCompatActivity` have over `ActionBarActivity`? And what are advantages of `AppCompatActivity`? Could somebody supply a few samples?

**PS:** what surprised me most is that `AppCompatActivity` which is extended from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` is the direct parent class of `ActionBarActivity`! I mean actually now that `ActionBarActivity` can do anything that `AppCompatActivity` can do, why did Android pushed out the latter?

Meanwhile, I saw a blog post that states: "*It's not a rename from `ActionBarActivity` to `AppCompatActivity`, the internal logic of `AppCompat` is available via `AppCompatDelegate`*", so what's the "*internal logic*" of `AppCompat`? What can `AppCompatDelegate` do? Could somebody post some code about this?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Comment: I have read it, it is a introduction, too shallow.

Comment: AppCompatActivity is parent class of ActionBarActivity. And for more idea you need to look into code.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

As Chris wrote, new deprecated version of `ActionBarActivity` (the one extending `AppCompatActivity` class) is a safe to use backward compatibility class. Its deprecation is just a hint for you asking to use new `AppCompatActivity` directly instead. `AppCompatActivity` is a new, more generic implementation which uses `AppCompatDelegate` class internally.

If you start a new development, then you should rather use new `AppCompatActivity` class right away. If you have a chance to update your app, then replace deprecated `ActionBarActivity` by the new activity as well. Otherwise you can stay with deprecated activity and there will be no difference in behavior at all.

Regarding `AppCompatDelegate`, it allows you to have new tinted widgets in an activity, which is neither `AppCompatActivity` nor `ActionBarActivity`.

For instance, you inherit an activity from an external library, which, in turn, does **not** inherit from `AppCompatActivity` but you want this activity to have tinted materials widgets (views). To make it happen you need to create an instance of `AppCompatDelegate` inside your activity, override methods of that activity like `addContentView()`, `setContentView()` etc. (see `AppCompatDelegate` javadoc for the full list of methods), and inside of those overridden methods forward the calls to the inner `AppCompatDelegate` instance. `AppCompatDelegate` will do the rest and your "old-fashion" activity will be "materialized".

Comment: Good Example .. Thank you @ sergej shafarenka

Comment: Can u please tell me that what happen when i will use Activity in place of Appcompactivity? I have searched but did not get the solution.Please help me

Answer (score 35):

It's mostly a name change: `ActionBarActivity` doesn't really describe everything it now does. You can safely use `ActionBarActivity` if you wish to. Think of it like a symlink.

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` is the direct parent class of `ActionBarActivity`, now that `ActionBarActivity` can do anything that `AppCompatActivity` can do, why `Android` pushed out the later?

Comment: @SilentKnight: As Chris wrote, it is mostly a name change. Quoting [the Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html): "The AppCompat Support Library started with humble, but important beginnings: a single consistent Action Bar for all API 7 and higher devices. In revision 21, it took on new responsibility: bringing material color palette, widget tinting, Toolbar support, and more to all API 7+ devices. With that, the name ActionBarActivity didn’t really cover the full scope of what it really did."

Comment: It is **not safe** to use deprecated classes, since they are subject to removal in future versions. Although you can easily replace all references to `ActionBarActivity` when it is dropped from the support library (e.g. when updating your app) I would recommend to avoid using it from now on.

Answer (score 12):

> The AppCompat Support Library started with humble, but important beginnings: a single consistent Action Bar for all API 7 and higher devices. In revision 21, **it took on new responsibility**: bringing material color palette, widget tinting, Toolbar support, and more to all API 7+ devices. With that, **the name ActionBarActivity didn’t really cover the full scope of what it really did**.

http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Comment: ..Can u please tell me that what happen when i will use Activity in place of Appcompactivity? I have searched but did not get the solution.Please help me

Answer (score 9):

`AppCompatActivity` was introduced into **Android-SDK** since the release of **android support appcompat library**.

`AppCompatActivity` is the direct child class of `FragmentActivity` of support v4 and the direct parent class of `ActionBarActivity`.

`AppCompatActivity` is the base class for activities that use the **support library action bar** features.

You can add an `ActionBar` to your activity when running on **API level 7 or higher** by extending this class for your activity and setting the activity theme to **Theme.AppCompat** or a similar theme.

As for support v7 appcompat library, it adds support for the **Action Bar** user interface design pattern. This library includes support for **material design** user interface implementations.

Here are a few of the key classes included in the v7 appcompat library:

- `ActionBar` - Provides an implementation of the action bar user
  interface pattern.
- `AppCompatActivity` - Adds an application activity class that can be
  used as a base class for activities that use the **Support Library
  action bar** implementation.
- `AppCompatDialog` - Adds a dialog class that can be used as a base
  class for **AppCompat** themed dialogs.
- `ShareActionProvider` - Adds support for a standardized sharing action
  (such as email or posting to social applications) that can be
  included in an action bar.

After you download the **Android Support Libraries**, this library is located in the */extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/* directory.

Comment: What about `android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat`? Is this just the old name of `AppCompatActivity`?

Answer (score 7):

Previously the only entry point into `AppCompat` was through the now deprecated `ActionBarActivity` class. Unfortunately this forced you into using a set Activity hierarchy which made things like using `PreferenceActivity` impossible.

see chris banes's  [support-libraries-v22-1-0](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) for more info

Comment: It's Chris's blog, very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The latest release of android support library, 22.1, deprecates the `ActionBarActivity` in favor of `AppCompatActivity`, which promises to bring a single consistent `ActionBar` for all devices starting with API Level 7 and above