# diffrence between Appcompact activity and actionbar activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

In Android What is the main difference between extending a class from `AppCompatActivity` and `ActionBarActivity`? How do these classes differ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ActionBarActivity` is now deprecated. As of version 22.1 of the support library you should use `AppCompatActivity`.

Chris Banes (one of the authors of the AppCompat library) covered the refactor in detail [here](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/).

Comment: can you tell me the main difference?

Comment: Updated the answer with a link that explains it in detail

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBarActivity` is deprecated, you must use `AppCompatActivity` instead

[Source: developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)

Comment: can you tell me the main difference?

Comment: Found similar question asked before, [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29978777/2846982)

Comment: It has been deprecated but it can still be used, so it is not a "must" ! It is more preferably to use AppCompatActivity but not mandatory.