# Difference between ActionBarActivity and AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, android-appcompat

`AppCompatActivity` was added into the latest v7 support library. Now I am using `ActionBarActivity` in all my applications, but now it is showing a message saying `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated. Please tell me what is the difference between these two classes and how I have to use it.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797172/whats-the-enhancement-of-appcompatactivity-over-actionbaractivity

Answer (score 4):

You may also know that `ToolBar` is now added in replace of ActionBar. To support this new subclass of Activity is added which is now called AppCompatActivity. All functionality of actionBar is available in this class. For this reason `ActionBarActivity` is depricated & encouraged to use `AppCompatActivity`.