# In android Studio ,my main activity class does not extend the actionbaractivity

Tags: android

i m beginner in android app development. in android studio when i creat a new project , my main activity class does not extend the action bar activity class.
i mean there is written  that main Activity class extends action bar activity but
there appears a ---(dash) on the actionbaractivity. and shows the error that 
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity is deprecated. 
     i cant find the solution for this. please help me.

Comment: Then extends `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: entends AppCompatActivity there

Comment: [http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-appcompatactivity-goodbye-actionbaractivity/](http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-appcompatactivity-goodbye-actionbaractivity/)

Comment: Nishtha, try with this , public class YOURCLASSNAME extends ActionBarActivity and integrate appcompat 7 properly to your project.

Comment: write this lines in your build.gradle file, 
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797172/whats-the-enhancement-of-appcompatactivity-over-actionbaractivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797172/whats-the-enhancement-of-appcompatactivity-over-actionbaractivity)

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBarActivity` is depreciated for sdk version 22 and above, so you need to use `AppCompatActivity` instead of ActionBarActivity. Rest of your code will be same.

Comment: It's from version 22.1.0, not 21: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`AcitonBarActivity` is deprecated starting from version `22.1.0` of the support library.

Take a look at the following link:
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html
Android Support Library, revision 22.1.0 (April 2015) - Section "Changes for v7 appcompat library"

Now you need to use `AppCompatActivity`, so extend your `Activity` from this class and the warning will disappear.

If you look at the `build.gradle` of you app module you will see the exact version of the support libraries you're using.

Answer (score -1):

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; //delete it
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; // use this

extends ActionBarActivity // delete this
extends AppCompatActivity  // use this