# Alternative of ActionbarActivity for ToolBar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-actionbaractivity

ActionbarActivity is deprecated now so what is the alternative activity of ActionbarActivity for the Toolbar ??

My toolbar working fine, but I just want to know, there is any other way to do for toolbar ?  I don't need solution for what to do for toolbar.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DoneBar/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/donebar/DoneBarActivity.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionbarActivity`... That's the new way after `ActionbarActivity` was deprecated.

Comment: I did not notice any. The name change was to avoid the impression that the name `ActionbarActivity` gave...when it actually did more than backport the `ActionBar` to Android versions not having it through the framework.

Comment: Thanks @ElvisChweya I will search this and see you soon..!!

Answer (score -1):

ActionBarActivity is now deprecated. You may follow following site:
[Alternative of ActionbarActivity for ToolBar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797172/whats-the-enhancement-of-appcompatactivity-over-actionbaractivity)

Comment: thanks for your help but my question is not how to add toolbar? i have already done my toolbar but want to know what is activity to extends?

Comment: Ohh. You may extend AppCompatActivity.

Comment: You may check this site:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797172/whats-the-enhancement-of-appcompatactivity-over-actionbaractivity