# How do you change the theme of an app in Android Studio without getting rendering problems?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-theme, android-studio-2.2

I have been having this problem in Android studio where I create a project, and I try to change the theme but it always gives me rendering problems.
I try to change the styles.xml but it doesn't really seem to work.
Here's the theme I want:
[image: Material Light]

Whenever I try to select it, I get rendering problems:
[image: Rendering Problems]

Here's the error details:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:192)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:186)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor271.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$72(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As seen from the first line of the error log, it says

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.

So, Naturally I select the Appcompat Theme like so:
[image: AppCompat]

And this works without any problems:
[image: AppCompat Theme]

MainActivity.java file as requested:

```
 package com.example.moham.currencyconverter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that I can use any theme I want and make it work without rendering problems?

edited the java file to extend Activity, and that didn' solve the problem.
Instead, I now have an additional problem in the java code:
[image]
[image: java file]

Comment: Your primary issue is not related to the rendering problems, as that is mostly just IDE bugs. If you are using `AppCompatActivity`, you have to use a theme inherited from `Theme.AppCompat`. If you do not want to use a theme inherited from `Theme.AppCompat`, stop using `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: post your Acvtivity class

Comment: @NickanB: Do you mean the MainActivity.java?

Comment: yes , MainActivity.java

Comment: @CommonsWare: Where do I change that? I'm sorry if this seems like a noob question, but that's because it is.

Comment: @NickanB Done..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Answer (score 0):

As @CommonsWare rightly mentioned, your activity is extending **AppCombatActivity** due to which you have to use AppCombat theme.

Simply extend **Activity** instead of AppCombatActivity. It'll solve your problem.

But **prefer to use AppCombatActivity** as you'll be able to easily use design widgets like floatingActionButton, etc. Without AppCombat theme and activity you'll not be able to use them. 
Hope it helps.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797172/whats-the-enhancement-of-appcompatactivity-over-actionbaractivity) to know why to use AppCombatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity, Activity, etc.

Comment: Do you mean extend it in the MainActivity.java (Code just posted in the question above)?

Comment: @uddinstock yes exactly.

Comment: Why do you want to use activity in first place? If you remove AppCombatActivity various errors(error inflating floating button,error inflating coordinator layout) will occur. As a android dev you hav to update yourself with every google updates, not downgrade. Check the link i added in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @CommonsWare and @Vishal Puri explain to you , your problem should solve if you
Change

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

To

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```