# The impact of changing ActionBarActivity to AppCompatActivity

Tags: android

I'm working on an old Android project, did you know, what's the impact when I change **ActionBarActivity**  (that's deprecated) by **AppCompatActivity**  in all classes of the project ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from [sergej shafarenka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797172/whats-the-enhancement-of-appcompatactivity-over-actionbaractivity)

`ActionBarActivity` (the one extending `AppCompatActivity` class) is a safe to use backward compatibility class. Its deprecation is just a hint for you asking to use new `AppCompatActivity` directly instead. `AppCompatActivity` is a new, more generic implementation which uses `AppCompatDelegate` class internally.

If you start a new development, then you should rather use new `AppCompatActivity` class right away. If you have a chance to update your app, then replace deprecated `ActionBarActivity` by the new activity as well. Otherwise you can stay with deprecated activity and there will be no difference in behavior at all.

Regarding `AppCompatDelegate`, it allows you to have new tinted widgets in an activity, which is neither `AppCompatActivity` nor `ActionBarActivity`.

For instance, you inherit an activity from an external library, which, in turn, does **not** inherit from `AppCompatActivity` but you want this activity to have tinted materials widgets (views). To make it happen you need to create an instance of `AppCompatDelegate` inside your activity, override methods of that activity like `addContentView()`, `setContentView()` etc. (see `AppCompatDelegate` javadoc for the full list of methods), and inside those overridden methods forward the calls to inner `AppCompatDelegate` instance. `AppCompatDelegate` will do the rest and your "old-fashion" activity will be "materialized".

Comment: Thanks for reply, so if I understood correctly, if I make a copy of any occurrence of `ActionBarActivity` and replace with `AppCompatActivity` it will not affect my code?
Or do I do nothing at all and just use `AppCompatActivity` in the new activities created?

Comment: Even your first sentence is correct. Secondly you can use AppCompatActivity to your new activity.