# cannot resolve symbol "ActionBarActivity" in android studio 2.1.1

Tags: android

I am starting development of android apps so i downloaded android studio so, when i imported ActionBarActivity class from the source of android it's giving me error 
like this:-

Please check the error here:

[image: please check the error here]

I have tried many things like changing the path and everything but nothing works here is the image of my installed SDKs in android studio:-

Please check the SDK tools here:

[image: please check the SDK tools here]

Please help me if anyone knows what to do about this error

Comment: It seems that your build.gradle is misconfigured. Can you post your build.gradle code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution of this kind of problem:

1. Download the Android Support Repository from Android SDK Manager, SDK Manager icon will be available on Android Studio tool bar (or `Tools -> SDK Manager`).
2. then go in to extras and download `Android support repository`
   Then

Open your main module's `build.gradle` file and add following dependency for using action bar in lower API level

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Sync your project with gradle using the tiny Gradle icon available in toolbar (or Tools -> Android -> Sync Project With Gradle Files)

3. If you have done all steps or all are present already then u can change the extends as
   `AppBarActivity` to `AppCompatActivity` `(Public Class ClassName extends AppCompatActivity)` because AppBarActivity has been deprecated.

Comment: it worked, firstly i followed your steps and then now i have created new project so by default they gave me AppCompatActivity instead of Actionbaractivity thanks bro!!

Answer (score 25):

Change

`ActionBarActivity` to `AppCompatActivity`

Like this

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: Why this is necessary?

Comment: ´ActionBarActivity´ has been deprecated in favor of the new ´AppCompatActivity´. Read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797172/whats-the-enhancement-of-appcompatactivity-over-actionbaractivity

Comment: This was really my problem. Lost two hours and seen other answers, all wrong. This one solved.