# Replacing ActionBarSherlock With AppCompat

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar-compat

I'm currently working on a simple navigation drawer + sliding tab.

However, I wanted these a material design on my own app.

Therefore, I have no choice except to get rid off `ActionBarSherlock`. When in these attempt, I found that 2 types of imports which are as follows:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
```

has to be removed too. However, more errors seem to appear after removing it.

So, is there any other type of imports that could replace these 2 above?

Answer (score 14):

If you're going to use `appcompat-v7`, I am sure you have `support-v4` in your dependencies as well.

You can try replacing

- `com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment` with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
- `com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity` with 
  `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`

There are some good advices on migrating from ABS to AppCompat.

- [What are the common issues when migrating from ActionBarSherlock to ActionBarCompat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933944/what-are-the-common-issues-when-migrating-from-actionbarsherlock-to-actionbarcom)
- [ActionBarCompat (Part 3): Migrating from ActionBarSherlock](http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-migrating-actionbarsherlock)
- [Migrating from ActionBarSherlock to ActionBarCompat](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat)

Something to note with above examples is that `ActionBarActivity` is now deprecated and replaced by `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: I was confused as to why we need both android.support.v4 and android.support.v7. I thought each library was complete but that is not the case. In case someone else is wondering this, see this other answer addressing the differences http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271429/difference-between-android-support-v7-appcompat-and-android-support-v4