# confusing error...@actionbarsherlock library

Tags: android, android-studio

There is an confusing problem that I can't understand...

1. When I add actionbarsherlock as an library into any project then I got an error...

   like :

   ```
   F:\Android_En\Projects of Android\Task 12_Optices\opticseis_main\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
   Error:(510) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.
   Error:(90) Original attribute defined here.
   Error:(851) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.
   Error:(497) Original attribute defined here.
   Error:(858) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.
   Error:(503) Original attribute defined here.
   Error:(871) Attribute "itemBackground" already defined with incompatible format.
   Error:(808) Original attribute defined here.
   Error:(874) Attribute "actionBarSize" already defined with incompatible format.
   Error:(555) Original attribute defined here.
   Error:(876) Attribute "windowMinWidthMajor" already defined with incompatible format.
   Error:(554) Original attribute defined here.
   Error:(876) Attribute "windowMinWidthMinor" already defined with incompatible format.
   Error:(554) Original attribute defined here.
   Information:14 errors
   ```

   NOTE:
   Solution of problem: remove the library of actionbarsherlock from properties library
2. When I do not add actionbarsherlock as a library into any project then error will become...

   like:

   ```
   Error:_/_/ (_)___/_/  \_, /
   F:\Android_En\Projects of Android\Task 12_Optices\opticseis_main\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v14\values-v14.xml
   Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
   Error:(9) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar'.
   Error:(54) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light'.
   Error:(67) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Sherlock'.
   F:\Android_En\Projects of Android\Task 12_Optices\opticseis_main\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
   Error:(3949) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.
   Error:(3956) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.
   Error:(3963) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.
   Error:(1894) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
   Error:(1900) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar'.
   Error:(3629) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light'.
   Error:(3642) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Sherlock'.
   Error:(1904) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
   Error:(1907) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
   Error:(3021) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown'.
   Error:(3024) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar'.
   Error:(3151) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow'.
   Error:(3286) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
   Error:(3975) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock'.

   Information:19 errors
   ```

   NOTE:
   Solution of problem: add library as an actionbarsherlock into project properties..

Comment: don't use actionbarsherlock. It was deprecated and unsupported already for few years. Use a support actionbar instead. It has completely same functionality, and even more already.

Comment: yaah..but how to use support actionbar instead actionbarsherlock. Please..written in some details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197706/replacing-actionbarsherlock-with-appcompat
also google: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20migrate%20from%20actionbarsherlock
there are already hundreds of answers ready