# Using jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu with ActionBarSherlock gives "AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/background' with config ''."

Tags: android, debugging, gradle, compilation

I'm trying to use SlidingMenu with SherlockActionBar but the gradle keeps giving me the following error. Please help!

I have already tried downgrading the appsupport-v4 version to 18 from 28 but still doesn't work

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
D:\AndroidStudio\NNY\neredeNeYenir_Datetimepicker\build\intermediates\packaged_res\debug\values\values.xml:57:5-89: AAPT: warn: ignoring element 'g' with unknown namespace 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\4012345e714ae01fd13b2690ed0a225a\res\values\values.xml:153:5-155:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/background' with config ''.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\4012345e714ae01fd13b2690ed0a225a\res\values\values.xml:153:5-155:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar\954feacd7f89ddbf974fd53623ef63f3\res\values\values.xml:87:5-89:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/navigationMode' with config ''.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar\954feacd7f89ddbf974fd53623ef63f3\res\values\values.xml:87:5-89:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar\954feacd7f89ddbf974fd53623ef63f3\res\values\values.xml:87:5-89:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/displayOptions' with config ''.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar\954feacd7f89ddbf974fd53623ef63f3\res\values\values.xml:87:5-89:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar\954feacd7f89ddbf974fd53623ef63f3\res\values\values.xml:469:5-471:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/actionBarSize' with config ''.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar\954feacd7f89ddbf974fd53623ef63f3\res\values\values.xml:469:5-471:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar\954feacd7f89ddbf974fd53623ef63f3\res\values\values.xml:469:5-471:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/windowMinWidthMajor' with config ''.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar\954feacd7f89ddbf974fd53623ef63f3\res\values\values.xml:469:5-471:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar\954feacd7f89ddbf974fd53623ef63f3\res\values\values.xml:469:5-471:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/windowMinWidthMinor' with config ''.

C:\Users\MAK.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar\954feacd7f89ddbf974fd53623ef63f3\res\values\values.xml:469:5-471:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

Answer (score 1):

In your output you can see that you're still using the v7 support library, and getting errors because the different values in the library are duplicated in the ABS library. So you either get rid of the v7 or you update your project to work with AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarSherlock (which would make the project more maintainable).

If you decide to update the project to api 28, you can follow the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933944/what-are-the-common-issues-when-migrating-from-actionbarsherlock-to-actionbarcom).

Cheers!