# What is the best way checking users' internet connection to send notification when it is on?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am newbie about sending notification. I have knowledge on AlarmManager and on showing notification when AlarmManager fires. I fetch some websites, collect information from that websites and insert them into my database on my hosting.

I plan to create an android application that sends some of these inserted information to users as soon as they have internet connection. Actually, what I want to achive exactly is sending notification like Facebook, Twitter or Instagram (You know, when you turn on your connection, comments, retweets, likes, mentions etc. notifications are sent in a minute ). I thought this can be done by checking user's connection every 2 or 5 minutes with a background task in AlarmManager but it doesn't look like good for battery. There should be some more professional or logical solution. Can you show me a way to achive this?

**NOTE: I do not need connection control code. I just need to know which time range should i choose to check. Should I use alarmmanager or are there something else to manage the time range in background?**

Comment: please have a look an previous answer ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053996/android-notification-at-time?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `You can add these lines to your manifest and make a receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>`
```

and make a class as below

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    if(checkInternet(context))
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Network Available Do operations",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }

}

boolean checkInternet(Context context) {
    ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager(context);
    if (serviceManager.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

public class ServiceManager {

```
Context context;

public ServiceManager(Context base) {
    context = base;
}

public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: Indeed, there is no need to perform a check every few minutes. By implementing the `BroadcastReceiver ` the `onReceive` method will be called every time a connection change is detected (every time the user connects or disconnects from a wireless network or mobile data).

Comment: This will work for checking if there is network connection. But not if the network connection is connected to the internet.

Comment: Yessss, this is what i looking for :) I will have to change "android.net.conn.connectivity_change" for N or higher android version. It is deprecated for N and higher one. Thanks for your code, you saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check internet connectivity by adding this lines of code, and for better understanding, you should create a parent class of all activities and place this code there and extend Base Activity(Parent) in all child activities and every time it will execute when any activity gets created.

`public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }`

Comment: Actually, I want to know how i manage the checking time range. With AlarmManager every a few minutes or are there any way better. But thanks for code example.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, I hope it will resolve your issue.

For reference: https://github.com/oscarjiv91/Android-Check-Internet-Connection

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ConnectionService extends Service {

    // Constant
    public static String TAG_INTERVAL = "interval";
    public static String TAG_URL_PING = "url_ping";
    public static String TAG_ACTIVITY_NAME = "activity_name";

    private int interval;
    private String url_ping;
    private String activity_name;

    private Timer mTimer = null;

    ConnectionServiceCallback mConnectionServiceCallback;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public interface ConnectionServiceCallback {
        void hasInternetConnection();
        void hasNoInternetConnection();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        interval = intent.getIntExtra(TAG_INTERVAL, 10);
        url_ping = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_URL_PING);
        activity_name = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_ACTIVITY_NAME);

        try {
            mConnectionServiceCallback = (ConnectionServiceCallback) Class.forName(activity_name).newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new CheckForConnection(), 0, interval * 1000);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    class CheckForConnection extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isNetworkAvailable();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mTimer.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url_ping);
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

        int timeoutConnection = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

        int timeoutSocket = 7000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        try{
            httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            mConnectionServiceCallback.hasInternetConnection();
            return true;
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mConnectionServiceCallback.hasNoInternetConnection();
        return false;
    }

}
```

In your activity, where you want to start this service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectionService.class);
    // Interval in seconds
    intent.putExtra(ConnectionService.TAG_INTERVAL, 100);
    // URL to ping
    intent.putExtra(ConnectionService.TAG_URL_PING, "http://www.google.com");
    // Name of the class that is calling this service
    intent.putExtra(ConnectionService.TAG_ACTIVITY_NAME, this.getClass().getName());
    // Starts the service
    startService(intent);
```

Implement ConnectionService.ConnectionServiceCallback on your activity and override the methods:

```
@Override
public void hasInternetConnection() {
   // has internet
}

@Override
public void hasNoInternetConnection() {
   // no internet :(
}
```

Stop the service

```
stopService(new Intent(this, ConnectionService.class));
```

Comment: Actually, I want to know how i manage the checking time range. With AlarmManager every a few minutes or are there any way better. But thanks for code example.

Comment: @umitkilic please check my updated answer, and let me know this is what you are looking for.