# How to update activity every 2 minutes using broadcast receiver in Android?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am using broadcastreceiver to update the Activity every minute, however, I want to change it to every 2 minutes. How can I achieve that?

Below is the code for my function -

```
private void startMinuteUpdated() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);

        minuteUpdateReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                lastUpdatedTimeTextDeparture.setText(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")));
            }
    };
        registerReceiver(minuteUpdateReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startMinuteUpdated();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(minuteUpdateReceiver);
    }
```

Comment: you can also use alarm manager for that, and can set repeating alarm depending upon your interval, you can check this answer over here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17099023/5353830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter your current implementation to read the minutes from current time and if its remainder by 2 is 0 then do your stuff, or else return. Doing this will allow you to update when the minutes are in even value (i.e. running every second minute).

```
if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) % 2 != 0){
   // don't proceed further
   return;
}

// update the activity
```

Comment: there is no minute variable in my code though, would you be able to edit the code?

Comment: so I do not need teh ACTION_TIME_TICK and the broadcast receiver anymore?

Comment: You do need that in order to trigger the event when a minute is changed... just use the code I referenced inside the onReceive method